# What to enter in the Devcert Password asked during expo project...?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using **Expo-cli** and **React Native** for project and i have a project named as "Formik" when i start the project in VS Code Terminal and type **expo start** all process is good.

But the problem arise when i click on the button **Run in web Browser** it prompts a message that starting your project in web broswer but when i see the **VS Code Terminal** it is asking me for a **Devcert password** which i don't know what password i should type in that particular field.

Please help me out in this and how i can able to run my project again in web browser.

Thanks in advance..!!

i am enclosing the message and i am using the following versions of software

**Expo-cli : 3.20.1**

**React-native : 2.0.1**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue is described [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1935), on expo-cli GitHub. What worked for me was running expo with this parameter.

```
expo start --no-https
```

Answer (score 0):

The password you are being asked to provide is the one for the new devCert. So, choose what you wish and can remember for the Certificate Authority to use for generating your new devCert. Having provided it the process will continue and provide you with a https url on your localhost to continue. I hope this meets your need.